# In laravel 8, trying to sellect a few model attributes of a query and paginate the results

Tags: filter, pagination, attributes, laravel-8, laravel-livewire

I am trying to filter a few attributes of my restaurant model. The restaurant model consists of 30 attributes and I need just four of them to send to a [Livewire](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/laravel-echo) component.

```
$myRestaurants = Restaurant::active()->valid()->paginate(10);
```

I can't use `pluck('id', 'name', 'icon')` or `only('id', 'name', 'icon')` to select the attributes I need and the object returns with all the data I don't want to be sent to the Livewire component.

Answer (score 1):

There's 2 ways you can achieve this;

Using the `select()` method on your query:

```
$myRestaurants = Restaurant::active()
    ->valid()
    ->select('id', 'another_col', 'and_another')
    ->paginate(10);
```

**Or** passing a second array parameter to `paginate()`:

```
$myRestaurants = Restaurant::active()
    ->valid()
    ->paginate(10, ['id', 'another_col', 'and_another']);
```

In Laravel 8, the definition of paginate can be seen below, and it is the `$columns` array you need to set.

```
public function paginate($perPage = 15, $columns = ['*'], $pageName = 'page', $page = null) { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks, both ways are correct if i needed to fetch data directly from restaurant model's table (then the 'icon' column would be there to fetch). But in may case i've used a getIconAttribute() in Restaurant model that make a URL based on another field... I want to have these getters in my collections.

Comment: I test the 2nd way you mantioned @Luck. When i call the 'logo' column, which the getIconAttribute() is calculated from, the getter works! :) and my object contains all i needed. Thakns by the way.

Comment: @ehsanmohiti Glad to be of help! If you could mark the answer please, trying to build my reputation count :)